# decoding XML in golang

Tags: xml, go

I'm trying to decode the following xml. For some reasons I can't decode the `Id`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

var data = `
<g xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ad="http://www.myschema.com/schema/ad/v1">
    <a xlink:href="http://example.com" data-bind="121">lala</a>
    <ad:ad id="1060469006">
</g>
`

type Anchor struct {
    DataBind  int    `xml:"data-bind,attr"`  
    XlinkHref string `xml:"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink href,attr"`
    Id int  `xml:"http://www.myschema.com/schema/ad/v1 id,attr"` 
}

type Group struct {
    A Anchor `xml:"a"`
}

func main() {
    group := Group{}
    _ = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &group)

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", group.A)
}
```

[Play](http://play.golang.org/p/EQDrFDWCHs)

Answer (score 4):

The structs you are decoding into are looking for a `ad:id` attribute on the `<a>` element in the XML.  There are two reasons this isn't working:

1. the `id` attribute is on a different element.
2. the `id` attribute is not in the `http://www.myschema.com/schema/ad/v1` namespace.  Attributes without a namespace prefix do not inherit the namespace of their element: instead they are part of the blank namespace.

So to fix this, first you need another field in `Group` with the tag `xml:"http://www.myschema.com/schema/ad/v1 ad"`, and the struct definition for that field needs its own field with the tag `xml:"id,attr"`.

Comment: Item 2: that's not how I understand the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting - "...the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear..". So it seems to be a bit ambiguous to me.

Comment: And the part just before what you quoted says "Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute names".  As far as generic XML processing tools go, these attributes are considered to not belong to any namespace (i.e. the blank namespace).